# Is there a way i can make psfrag replace every number in a plot?

Tags: plot, gnuplot, psfrag

I want to replace every number in the axis of a plot. Can psfrag do this?

If not, is there any other tool i can use to get the same effect?

Comment: You can use IPE, InkScape, Win or Xfig.